# Tell MSDeploy.exe to skip deploying a few select files in subsequent deployments

Tags: asp.net, .net, msdeploy

How do you tell MSDeploy.exe to skip deploying a few select files in subsequent deployments?

For e.g. I deploy a package that has files A, B and C. Then, I make another fresh build and therefore another package of the same application, only this time with the new version of the binaries A, B and C.

Now, I want MSDeploy.exe to deliver/deploy only files A and C, and to not deploy the new version of file B.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a rule in the config file if you wish to skip those files in every single deployment.

The config file is located at C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2. It is called msdeploy.exe (XML Config File). The sample config file is in the same directory as masdeploy.exe.configsettings.example

Please post your solutions or any other findings.